# Repeating CSS grid layout for n elements with whitespace

Tags: html, css

I want to get a CSS Grid that has a lot of whitespace (empty cells) around the items. For that I want every nth + x item to fill a specific position, so that they are beautiful aligned.

An example how it should look like one day:

[image: whitespace grid]

In my code example below I did a very rough example that sets three different areas and some whitespace that should not get filled up as I explicit place each `.item`.

https://codepen.io/they-are/pen/NZQGwr?editors=1100

I expect to not do that for each (n) items but repeat the grid pattern for all the following items. So the 1st and 4th, 2nd and 5th, 3rd and 5th item have the same position but always starting with `3n + 1` and ending with `3n + 3`. Currently it is only overlaying themselfes.

Comment: Could you dynamically insert style sheets depending on the content?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with CSS alone. You could use JavaScript or dynamically create style sheet with `<style> /* your dynamically created rules */</style>`.

Comment: To be honest I cannot believe that there is no (not hacky) solution for this. There is [a video specific about whitespace in CSS Grid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfIjFeBLhyA) by @jensimmons, who is one of the mothers of this specification. And of cause it is working for her 5 elements, but what if one would have 50 elements? There must be a solution to repeat the pattern, don't you agree?

Comment: I agree that there should be a possibility to dynamically adjust the values of CSS properties according to the counter, but alas I think there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it, by strategically inserting empty filler items into the grid HTML code like this:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 11vw;
  grid-gap: 1vw;
}

.item {
}
.item:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}
.item:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 4;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}
.item:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.filler {
  border: 1px solid rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.15);
  background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.02);
}
.filler:before {
  content: 'filler';
  color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5)
}
.filler:nth-of-type(n + 1) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <span class="filler"></span>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>

  <div class="item">D</div>
  <span class="filler"></span>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>

  <div class="item">G</div>
  <span class="filler"></span>
  <div class="item">H</div>
  <div class="item">I</div>
</div>
```

You could do it without fillers, if you use margins together with bigger row/column spans:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: calc(100vw / 9);
  grid-gap: 1vw;
}

.item {
  counter-increment: item;
}
.item:before {
  content: "#" counter(item);
}
.item:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: red;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  /* this item should only span 2 rows, but the margin below 
   * calculates just to span one row plus the gap, so in the 
   * end it looks as if this item does not span 3 but 2 rows.
   */
  grid-row-end: span 3;
  margin-bottom: calc(100vw / 9 + 1vw);
}
.item:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 4;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}
.item:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.filler {
  border: 1px solid rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.15);
  background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.02);
}
.filler:nth-of-type(n + 1) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>AA</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>

  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>

  <div class="item">G</div>
  <div class="item">H</div>
  <div class="item">I</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the interesting idea but let's say I cannot add the filler elements by code and do not want to use JavaScript. Would it be possible to take the last element `.item:nth-of-type(3n+3)` and add a pseudo element after it which is recognized by the grid?

Comment: No, you couldn't. A pseudo element is a child of its parent. It is therefore not a child of its parent parent. It cannot be a grid item on the same leven as its parent. This might be possible with subgrid, but thats a thing of the future.

Comment: @Philipp I added a new solution to my answer, which doesn't use fillers, but margins

Comment: thanks again! Yes you are right, that is possible because following items have no space to float up in there specific row. However this is possible with the specific example I used. As soon as you specifiy some more items and when the items get a bit more nested, you'll go crazy with the margins.
E.g. if you set `.item:nth-of-type(3n+2)` to
```grid-column-start: 4;
grid-column-end: span 2;
grid-row-end: span 1; ```
you need to rearrange the margins.
Sorry for bothering you but I really want to understand the possibilities and ask myself whether there is no "logic" solution for this.

Comment: I assure you. I worked several times with grid and made many experiments with it. If I'd know of a non-hacky solution, Id' tell you.

Comment: It's not that complicated. It should always be possible to fully pave the grid with adjacent tiles and then set the margins according to gain white-space: See here for an example https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/xovqbB?editors=1100. Note the lighter background show the full paving of the grid and the whitespace through margins. Even overlaps would be possible, if you use negative margins.

Comment: The example above now has addidional checkered background to show the grid tracks

Comment: this is a neat solution. Thank you very much again. But still I would count it as a workaround as we need to fill up the grid completely to avoid items filling up the whitespace. 
I did something similiar in the past days when diving into CSS grid and ended with a solution which combines `grid` and `flex` as I fill up the space as well and align its content with flex: https://codepen.io/they-are/pen/PrMKPG

All your answers are great and usable, I hope it is fine to nor mark it as "answered" as I really want to find the best solution for this and there might be some other answers.:)

Comment: @Philipp Good luck with that :) IMHO there is no other chance of getting this to work than with workarounds. There is no such thing as repeated areas in the spec. Also the `-grid-auto-columns/-rows` is flawed in the definition whilst there may be technical aspects for defining it like this.